# Composite key where one of the ID-components don't always update

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Im using Entity Framework 6.

Given the following models:

```
MyType (Id+Language are keys)
- Id
- Language // will be represented by values like "en", "no", "dk", "de"
- Label

MyValue (Id+SomeOtherEntityId+Language are keys)
- Id
- SomeOtherEntityId
- Language
- Value
```

I'd like the `Id` column in `MyTypes` to auto increment whenever a new language is given for that Id, if that makes sense.

Example:

```
context.MyTypes.Add(new MyType { Label = "Label", Language = "no" });
context.MyTypes.Add(new MyType { Label = "Label", Language = "da" });
context.MyTypes.Add(new MyType { Label = "Label", Language = "nl" });
```

This gives me a database that looks like the following:

```
| Id | Language | Label |
|----|----------|-------| 
| 1  | no       | Label |
| 2  | da       | Label |
| 3  | nl       | Label |
```

While what I really want is this:

```
| Id | Language | Label  |
|----|----------|--------| 
| 1  | no       | Label  |
| 1  | da       | Label  |
| 1  | nl       | Label  | 
| 2  | no       | Label2 |
| 2  | da       | Label2 |
| 2  | nl       | Label2 |
```

I have currently set my ID column as an Identity, thus making it auto incrementing.

1. Is it possible, from a database perspective, to configure this to be auto incrementing, depending on the Language column?
2. Is this configurable via EntityFramework?

I guess an alternative would be to have a separate Type-table with just an ID, and then link the Labels for different languages to this. However, I was hoping to avoid that simply because this structure is so simple, and having another table just for the ID's sake seems to me to just add some unnecessary complexity.

Another alternative could be to control this from code (when inserting new MyTypes, get the correct ID first and then add the rest).

Is there any best practices concerning this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

what you try to do can't be done, in my knowledge. (identity is one distinct value by row)

two tables seems right to me:

tableHead(Id, Code, Blabla)

```
tableTrans(Id, ExtId, Language, Value), with ExtId as a FK
```

or

```
tableTrans(ExtId, Language, Value) with a composite Key comprisong the FK
```

then you get you translation by a Code value and a Language value and get readable code.